# Django model creating geography not geometry fields

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, sqlgeography, sqlgeometry

I have a Django model in which i declare `maplocation = models.PointField()` I'd like to work with geography not geometry, if i use python manage.py sql  it maps as `"maplocation" geometry(POINT,4326) NOT NULL`,

what do i need to do so that the translation will be correct?

Answer (score 2):

Don't really know, but some tips:

1. You need to have PostGIS 1.5+ installed.
2. Define field like this: `maplocation = models.PointField(geography=True)`.
3. Set model manager to `django.contrib.gis.db.models.GeoManager` (I think this is not required to use geography, but You will need it later to make queries).